# How to save user input and JComboBox selection?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextfield

I'm developing my first (extremely basic) Java app. I'm having trouble though with saving user information; specifically, appending user input from a textfield to a JComboBox selection. How do I do this? As of now I have:

```
String comps[] = {Computer 1, Computer 2, Computer 3}; //array for JComboBox
jcbb = new JComboBox<String>(comps); //create JComboBox

if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Save")) { //user hits the Save button

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //string to hold data
        sb.append((String) macTF.getText()); //get data from textfield
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append((String) jcbb.getSelectedItem()); //get JComboBox item
        sb.append(" ");
        //***what to do with the held data?***
    }
```

I know I'm missing a lot, but just a nudge in the right direction will help. I have been searching through books and the Web, and have found so many different answers, but I cannot apply them. Do I output StringBuilder to text file and load that? Or build an array some how with both sets of data? Or something completely different?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addItem` method ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28java.lang.Object%29)):

```
if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Save")) { //user hits the Save button
    String toAdd = (String) macTF.getText(); //get data from textfield
    jcbb.addItem(toAdd); //add String to the combo box
}
```

Plus you gonna have a problem here:

```
String comps[] = {Computer 1, Computer 2, Computer 3}; //array for JComboBox
jcbb = new JComboBox<String>(comps); //create JComboBox
```

That should be:

```
String comps[] = {"Computer 1", "Computer 2", "Computer 3"}; //array for JComboBox
jcbb = new JComboBox(comps); //create JComboBox
```

Comment: Thank you talnicolas for the quick response! Forgive my ignorance, but will the addItem add the the text field data as a new combo box selection or assign the text field data to an existing combo box selection?

Comment: @Sett What do you mean by *combo box selection*?

Answer (score 0):

- [`JComboBox#addItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28E%29) allows you to add an item to the combobox, or [`JComboBox#insertItemAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#insertItemAt%28E,%20int%29) if you want to insert at a certain index
- [`JComboBox#removeItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeItem%28java.lang.Object%29) allows you to remove an item.

So a possible solution is the following, although the drawback is that it generates a lot of events due to the adding/removal of elements and the changes in selection. However, that is the behavior you are looking for

```
public <E> void replaceComboBoxItem( JComboBox<E> combo, E itemToReplace, E replacement ){
   boolean selected = combo.getSelectedItem() == itemToReplace;
   combo.insertItemAt( replacement, indexOf( combo, itemToReplace ) );
   combo.removeItem( itemToReplace );
   if ( selected ){
      combo.setSelectedItem( itemToReplace );
   }
}
private <E> int indexOf( JComboBox<E> combo, E item ){
  for( int i =0; i < combo.getItemCount(); i++ ){
    if ( combo.getItemAt( i ).equals( item ) ){
       return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

And then you could use

```
replaceComboBoxItem( jcbb, jcbb.getSelectedItem(), sb.toString() );
```

Note: code was just typed here, could contain small syntax errors